# use different css classnames for twitter's bootstrap popover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm working on bootstrap popover. I wonder if one could use other css classnames as "popover". I've tried with specifying another name (e.g. "mypopover") using popover's template option and changed my css stylesheet accordingly.

Going this way, bootstrap used my new class names but as a result all popups appeared empty - they did not have any content nor titles. Is the name "popover" hard coded or is threre a way to use my own names?

Comment: Why not go into the bootstrap css and change or extract the lay-out css? You could make your own class for the styling and make a popover have the classes `popover mypopover`.

Comment: I had to change only 2 lines of code in bootstrap-popover.js. Changed ".popover" to ".mypopover". In addition I used the template option to define my class names - very easy to implement.